# How do I install Ubuntu on a USB Flash Drive?

Tags: usb

My laptop does not have enough space to Install Ubuntu and I need to Install it on a USB Flash Drive. How do I install it?

Comment: @karel I noticed that right after marking this one as duplicate. Vanson, please don't ask the same question again and again. They will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either UNetbootin or LiLi(Linux Live) USB creator to create a live USB with persistence(dedicated partition for the live OS) from the ISO which can be downloaded from [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Answer (score 0):

First of all download the image file and then follow the steps given below...

1. Open Start up Disk creator from the Dash home by typing name as Start up Disk Creator.
2. Select Image
3. Select Destination Disk(Pen Drive in your case.)
4. Make Start up Disk.

There you go........

Comment: You can accept it as answer if you got it...and also vote it up... :)